# ETrade Authorization API - what are shared secret and token secret?

Tags: oauth, oauth-1.0a, etrade-api

On the E*Trade authorization api [documentation for Get Request Token](https://apisb.etrade.com/docs/api/authorization/request_token.html#/definition/GetRequestToken), it states that the oauth_signature is generated with "the `shared secret` and `token secret`".

When I generated my sandbox key, I was presented with the following information:

```
Individual Consumer Key
Your active SANDBOX API key is: abc123, and secret is: def456.
```

What are `shared secret` and `token secret`, and how do they map to the values provided above?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to generate the signature for the purposes of [Get Request Token](https://apisb.etrade.com/docs/api/authorization/request_token.html#/definition/GetRequestToken).

Both the `SANDBOX API key` and `SANDBOX API secret` are needed.

I believe `shared secret` refers to the `SANDBOX API secret`. It seems that `token secret` is not needed to generate the `oauth_signature` for Get Request Token.

Here is my implementation of generating the `oauth_signature` in JavaScript using the [oauth-sign](https://github.com/request/oauth-sign/blob/18a2513da6ba7a2c0cd8179170d7c296c7625137/index.js) library

```js
const oauthsign = require("oauth-sign");

const oauth_consumer_key = "..."; // "SANDBOX API key"
const consumer_secret =  "..."; // "secret"
const oauth_timestamp = "1614463663"; // current time in seconds
const oauth_nonce = "123abc";
const oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
const oauth_callback = "oob"; // out-of-band callback
const base_uri = "https://apisb.etrade.com/oauth/request_token"; // N.B. "apisb"

const oauth_signature = oauthsign.hmacsign(
  "GET",
  base_uri,
  { oauth_consumer_key, oauth_timestamp, oauth_nonce,
    oauth_signature_method, oauth_callback },
  consumer_secret
);
const paramsString = Object.entries({
  oauth_consumer_key, oauth_timestamp, oauth_nonce,
  oauth_signature_method, oauth_callback, oauth_signature
}).map(([k, v]) => `${k}=${v}`).join("&");

const result = `${base_uri}?${paramsString}`;
console.log(result);

// will produce a URL like
// https://apisb.etrade.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_consumer_key=...&oauth_timestamp=1614463663&oauth_nonce=123abc&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_callback=oob&oauth_signature=...
```

Answer (score 0):

A shared secret is your "permanent" client/consumer secret given to you by Etrade (can be sandbox (for testing purposes) and production (live)). A token secret is more "transitory" - it is generated whenever a new token is obtained. The two secrets are concatenated to form a key which is used to create an oauth signature to sign your requests.

Comment: But you don't have a token yet when you're calling GetRequestToken--it "begins the OAuth process".  But the Request header documentation is requiring "Signature generated with the shared secret and token secret" [sic] as of Feb 2024.  So it's a copy-paste error in the eTrade documentation??  Or how do you get the "token secret" to sign the first GetRequestToken if not?